# Do USBs with hybrid images content require boot flag?

Tags: boot

I want use hybrid image to create an USB Ubuntu installer. All I know at this point is that I need to paste the contents of the ISO directly into a USB partition, but will it work without boot flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hybrid ISO images are intended to be written directly to the storage device, rather than a partition on the storage device (i.e. so you'd write it to `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sdb1`, for example).  The image itself contains a partition table, so you shouldn't need to adjust things after writing.

Comment: ... That sucks, I need to find an *empty* USB now...